# ajax response contains the html for the whole page instead of the content of text editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, ckeditor

i am working with ckeditor.I used ajax to send the content of the ckeditor using post method.My plan is to show the response in a div .But in response i get the html for the whole page enclodes by html tag instead of only the editor's content.What is going on here? How can i get only the editor's content

[image]

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
echo $_POST['content'];
}
?>

<html>
<head>
  <script  src='ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action='test.php' method='post'>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <input type='button' value='submit' onClick='lol(event);'>
    </form>
    <div id='content' style='border:2px solid black;'>

    </div>
            <script>

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
function lol(event){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
       if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
           //document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=xhr.response;  
           alert(xhr.responseText);
       }
    }
    var value=CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    var params = "content="+value;
    xhr.open('POST','test.php',true);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(params);
    //alert(value);
}

            </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are getting the expected response. AJAX is just like any other HTTP request, it returns the whole thing. It is up to you to handle the response.

Comment: i am sending to post array only the content of text editor with the variable "value" .How can it return all the page?i need a solution for this

Comment: jQuery's $.load takes optional selectors to only return the part of the dom you want, but under the hood, it's just parsing the text into dom and then selecting them.  You'd need to do the same: just parse out the portion you wanted (and the easiest way to do that, if it's valid html, is just to convert it into real dom nodes and use dom methods to select the portion you want and return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You use `echo`, the response is sent and then the html is sent. If you want to stop after `echo`, use `die();`:

```
<?php  
  if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    die($_POST['content']);
  }
?>
```

Also, you should check that content is set:

```
<?php  
  if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['content'])) {
    die($_POST['content']);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution by adding variable to Javascript variable which called params and this variable to check if already these items opened or not and prevent main items to not open more than 1 time even if u called your page by ajax , to be clear try like that
  `var params = "content="+value+"isopened=1";`
then use php if statement like if there is no required variable then print your main items and this will only happen one time when u will visit the page directly with no  ajax request

```
<?PHP
    if(!$_POST['isopened'])
    {
    echo "home elements";
    }
?>
```